# CASE in SQL Server with null rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

New in SQL Server and stack. This is my first question if something is wrong please help me to correct

I want to be able to share entire query because its too big but below is my final output

```
personno personcat answervale personno personcat answervale 
-----------------------------------------------------------
12         1          yes        null     null     null
12         2          no          12      1        test
null       null       null        12      2        check
```

but I want to arrange this final output

```
 personcat personno answervale personcat personno answervale
 ------------------------------------------------------------
  1         12     yes           1        12         test

 personcat personno answervale personcat personno answervale
  2       12     no           2        12         check
```

As said above, I need only two rows, but I am getting rows with all answervale

Things which I tried:

1. case based on personcat
2. I use union added personcat in where but still not getting expected output

If anyone can suggest some other way to get expected output - please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your query. We can't help you without seeing your query

Comment: ..its is not clear how/why you arrange (expected) output (from the given output).

Comment: @Squirrel  my actual query is too big to post hear it contain more then 20 full outer join so this is not possible so i try to create scenirio  and want some suggestation .

Comment: @xerx593 output i am getting i need to arrenge that as expected because i need first output for my reporting and second i need to pass to one batch job that batch job accept input as expected output

Comment: Can you explain why you've written your query in a way to produce your first final output? Maybe the problem to fix is really there.

Comment: use min or max function with group by personno column to eliminate null values.

Comment: @DT  hi i try to create sceniro u can try to create temp table and insert data into it

Comment: you can use http://sqlfiddle.com to add your query